# GPIO: Numbering Changed after Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, kernel, ubuntu-22.04

I have a strange effect with GPIOs.

We are using intel-based single-board mini PCs featuring also some GPIOs.
As we were using Ubuntu MATE 20.04 on them, GPIOs via sysfs worked out of the box.

Now, after upgrading to Ubuntu MATE 22.04, it seems that the numbering of GPIOs have changed.

Just to be sure that the effect is not caused by some config or additionally installed packages, I reproduced it by booting two different live USB sticks. One with Ubuntu MATE 20.04, the other with Ubuntu MATE 22.04

**Ubuntu MATE 20.04 - Kernel 5.4.0-104-generic**

```bash
/sys/class/gpio# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

/sys/class/gpio# uname -r
5.4.0-104-generic

/sys/class/gpio# ll
total 0
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 12:13 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 12:13 gpiochip267 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:03/gpio/gpiochip267
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 12:13 gpiochip310 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:02/gpio/gpiochip310
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 12:13 gpiochip357 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:01/gpio/gpiochip357
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 12:13 gpiochip434 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:00/gpio/gpiochip434
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 15:06 unexport
```

**Ubuntu MATE 22.04 - Kernel 5.15.0-41-generic**

```bash
/sys/class/gpio# lsb_release 
No LSB modules are available.
root@tox-hmi3:/sys/class/gpio# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

/sys/class/gpio# uname -r
5.15.0-41-generic

/sys/class/gpio# ll
total 0
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 14:42 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 14:42 gpiochip779 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:03/gpio/gpiochip779
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 14:42 gpiochip822 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:02/gpio/gpiochip822
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 14:42 gpiochip869 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:01/gpio/gpiochip869
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 10 14:42 gpiochip946 -> ../../devices/platform/INT3452:00/gpio/gpiochip946
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug 10 14:42 unexport
```

Exporting PINs still seems to work, but of course not with the numbers that used to exist.

```bash
/sys/class/gpio# echo 404 > export 
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

/sys/class/gpio# echo 869 > export 

root@tox-hmi3:/sys/class/gpio# ls
export  gpio869  gpiochip779  gpiochip822  gpiochip869  gpiochip946  unexport
```

However, now I do not know to were my PINs have moved.

What did change between Kernel version 5.4 and 5.15 that would cause the detection of GPIOs to result in different numbering?

Comment: Side note: isn't `/sys/class/gpio` [obsolete](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/Documentation/ABI/obsolete/sysfs-gpio?h=v5.16&id=fe95046e960b4b76e73dc1486955d93f47276134)? Maybe it's time to start using tools from the `gpiod` package.

Comment: Sure, you are right.
But fortunately sysfs is still there, which gives us time to bug the developer of a software we depend upon to migrate to gpiod in the mid-term.